# Create progress bar with JS Countdown Timer

Tags: javascript, html, timer, progress

I am trying to create a progress bar with the JS Countdown Timer, I need it when it reaches 00 00 00 00 the progress bar is 100% and the bar will go forward while this counter is going down in time. Thanks!

The current code is as follows:

```js
// =================================================================================
// Countdown Timer
// =================================================================================

var ctd = document.getElementById("countdown");
countdown();
function countdown() {
  // Contador ......
  var launch_date = new Date("9, 28, 2017 7:07:00");
  var days;
  var hours;
  var minutes;
  var seconds;
  var rest;
  var now = new Date();
  seconds = rest = Math.floor((launch_date.getTime() - now.getTime()) / 1000);
  days = zero(Math.floor(seconds / 86400));
  seconds -= days * 86400;
  hours = zero(Math.floor(seconds / 3600));
  seconds -= hours * 3600;
  minutes = zero(Math.floor(seconds / 60));
  seconds -= minutes * 60;
  seconds = zero(Math.floor(seconds));
  function zero(n) {
    return (n < 10 ? "0" : false) + n;
  }
  rest <= 0
    ? (days = hours = minutes = seconds = "00")
    : setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
  ctd.innerHTML =
    '<li><div><span class="countnumber">' +
    days +
    "</span><br> Dia" +
    (days > 1 ? "s" : "") +
    "</div></li>" +
    '<li><div><span class="countnumber">' +
    hours +
    "</span><br> Hora" +
    (hours > 1 ? "s" : "") +
    "</div></li>" +
    '<li><div><span class="countnumber">' +
    minutes +
    "</span><br> Minuto" +
    (minutes > 1 ? "s" : "") +
    "</div></li>" +
    '<li class="color"><div><span class="countnumber">' +
    seconds +
    "</span><br> Segundo" +
    (seconds > 1 ? "s" : "") +
    "</div></li>";
}
```

```html
<div class="countdown">
  <ul id="countdown"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried with the progress bar?

Answer (score 0):

We won't do your work here on SO.

Research, write some code and if you have problems, you can ask here.

Anyways, you can easily achieve that using a div, that you resize to you needs (set the width to how broad you want it) and set a border on it. Like this:

```css
.bar {
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar" style="width: 200px;"></div>
<br/>
<div class="bar" style="width: 300px;"></div>
```

Just set its width according to your timer.

Comment: I know they will not do the job only I need to know what the variables are to add them to the progress bar of the script I'm using thanks!

Comment: What do you mean what the variables are? You have the starting time, convert that into seconds, take the seconds from your timer and calculate the %